# BootstrapValidator how to find rules for a field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How do I find if there are rules specified for a particular field?

e.g. conditional zip code validation. I want to apply the validation if it hasn't been applied before, otherwise just enable it.

```
  if (zipFieldElements == null) {
            $(registerForm).bootstrapValidator('addField', m.zipCodeFieldName, m.getZipCodeValidator());
   } else {
            bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators(m.zipCodeFieldName, true);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not worry and always call both. This works reliably (0.5.3):

```
bootstrapValidator.addField(mBehave.stateFieldName, {validators: {notEmpty: "The state cannot be empty"}, container: 'popover'});
bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators(mBehave.stateFieldName, true)
```